# Definir posição do foco do cursor no EditText

Tags: java, android, teclado

Existe alguma maneira de quando eu chamar o teclado virtual (`SoftKeyboard`) definir a posição do cursor?

Eu tenho um `EditText` que já vem preenchido por padrão o número `10`, quando o teclado iniciar quero o cursor fique logo depois do `0`, mas ele está vindo antes do `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível usando [**`EditText.setSelection`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setSelection(int)) + `editText.getText().length()`

Basta executar:

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Você pode chegar quando o campo estiver em foco e disparar o `setSelection` neste momento

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus)
    {
        if (hasFocus) {
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado Ezequiel, eu tinha entendido errado.

Comment: Imagina, desculpe se escrevi de uma forma que dificultou o seu entendimento :)

Comment: @EzequielMessore nada, foi falha de minha parte mesmo ;)

Comment: Toma meu +1... Muito bom!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.... Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Se pudessem me ajudar denovo na mesma questão eu agradeceria..... Tem como além da posição do foco vir todo o texto selecionado?

Comment: @MarcioVieira testa isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241487/3635