# É possivel selecionar todo o texto de EditText quando estiver em foco?

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho um `EditText` e quando uso:

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Gostaria que selecionasse o texto todo, é possível?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem duas maneiras, a primeira é mudar a propriedade do `EditText` no layout xml e adicionar:

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

A outra é via script, no `onCreate` você definir para selecionar tudo no focus:

```
editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```

Então depois pode usar:

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Não consegui efetuar o teste, mas creio que `selectAll` também funcione:

```
editText.selectAll();
```